# highcharts add more data in tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on a bar chart. I want to add additional data series in tooltip. I found I  can create another series and set visible as false. But that is not what I want because it will show on the chart.
I have a series like below:

```
  'series' : [
    {
        'name': '1 month ago ',
        'data': last_val

    },
    {
        'name': 'Current ',
        'data': current_val

    }            
  ]
```

`last_val` and `current_val` are two arrays. I want to add two additional data array in tooltip, my question is can I put the additional array as part of data in this series? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) or use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and add data

Comment: fixed the problem by setting both invisible and showInLegend to false